# Algorithm to find minimal number of subsets of a set of given conditions

Tags: algorithm, subset

For a given set of numbers `{12,13,15,21,22,26,6,14,27,28,29,30,39,40,4,17,25}` i want to find the minimum number of subsets which satisfies the two condition.

1. number of elements in each set is a constant i.e say for above
   example it is `5`.
2. In a subset any of the two elements satisfy the condition:
   `(num1-num2)% d != 0`. `num1>num2` and Where d is constant difference
   between two numbers.

for the example above: if `d=4` and number of elements in subset is `5` then one of the subset would be: `{12,13,15,22,17}`

I am looking for an algorithm to find the minimum number of subsets that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Well, you can brute-force it :)

Comment: Most likely, you will have no choice but to brute-force it, since this is slightly more complicated than "knapsack" style of problems.  The conditions do not necessarily apply to only one element, so there is no way to filter out potential members of a subset without knowing the other elements of that specific subset, so a subset has to be chosen before the condition can even be tested (although %d != 0 contradicts constant difference).  Since finding a minimum number of subsets is the requirement, rather than finding any matching subset, this will be a very computationally-intensive problem.

Comment: you said  `d` is constant difference between two numbers, then how does set `{12,13,15,22,17}` satisfies this ?

Comment: The example looks wrong: 13=17 (mod 4)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's not really 100% about programming. It's a standard discrete math exercise.

Let's do it in steps:

1. Amount of combinations of all possible subsets: **n!** where **n** is amount of elements in the first set. I'm assuming here that we're not allowed to repeat selected elements in a subset. And that the order of elements in subsets don't matter (otherwise we'd need to use Combinations instead of Permutations)
2. Now We're selecting only **r** elements, not all **n** of them, so now it's **n!/(n-r)!** Where r is the amount of elements in the subset.
3. The hardest part is finished. Now we need to add a condition, for which you can only take the previous **n!/(n-r)!** and substract amount of "bad" pairs of elements. Basically, excluding any permutations starting with forbidden values. Let's find all the forbidden values:
4. Two simple nested loops, checking the (num1-num2)% d != 0 for each pair, which will take around n*(n-1)/2 iterations. Or just n^2 iterations without dynamic changing the iterator in the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this greedily.

Partition your set into S[i] where initially S[i] = {s in S such that s % d == i}.

Then, repeatedly pick the k (5 in your example) largest subsets S[i] and remove one element from each.

Here's some slightly inefficient but simple code that implements this:

```
def part(S, k, d):
    "Split S into subsets of size<=d, each with elements unique mod k"
    parts = [[] for _ in xrange(k)]
    for s in S:
        parts[s % k].append(s)
    while sum(len(p) for p in parts):
        parts.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
        yield [x.pop() for x in parts[:d] if x]

S = [12,13,15,21,22,26,6,14,27,28,29,30,39,40,4,17,25]
for s in part(S, 6, 5):
    print sorted(s)
```

Output of this code, which shows subsets of size at most 5 such that no subset contains two numbers equal modulo 6:

```
[4, 14, 25, 30, 39]
[6, 13, 17, 27, 40]
[12, 21, 26, 28, 29]
[15, 22]
```

The sort of `parts` and while loop condition could be optimized away with a priority queue and a running counter, but that would obscure what's going on. The optimized form will run in O(n log n) time; as written it's O(n^2 log n)

[I should say, I'm pretty sure this solution is correct, but I can't quite see how to prove it. I'd be interested in seeing a proof (or a counterexample to show it's wrong).]

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def run(self, n,m):
        if len(n)<=1:
        return [n]             
        x = n[0:1]  //get 1st part
        y = n[1:]   //get remaining
        t = self.run(y,m)
        r=[]
        if t:
            r+=[x]  //add current element
            r+=[i for i in t if count(i)<=m]    // add fixed combinations
            r+=[ i+x for i in t if valid(i+x)]  // all combined combinations
        return r
def valid(combination):
    //code to check your condition
    (num1-num2)% d != 0
```